# Slow performance when hazel cast is on

Tags: java, performance, hazelcast

Slow performance when hazel cast is on.

I am new to hazelcast services and need some helps. Hope some responses here from the experts.

Subject refers, response of HTTP call is slow by 400% (2 seconds) when client hits the restful services as the diagram below. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByIpkcJW-nHLVHJWRzJkOHFPdkE

If one of the hazelcast is off, the response is faster (500 miliseconds)

There are around 3k results return from the HTTP restful services call.

Any advices on the setting that could solve the performance issues? Or the setup has issues

Below are other information about the restful services.

## HTTP URL and response data

```
URL: http://10.1.1.1/data/api/zipcode



 {"content":[{"resourceId":0,"version":0,"name":"00000","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":0,"active":true},
{"resourceId":1,"version":0,"name":"01000","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":4,"version":0,"name":"01500","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":5,"version":0,"name":"01502","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":6,"version":0,"name":"01503","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":7,"version":0,"name":"01504","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":8,"version":0,"name":"01505","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":9,"version":0,"name":"01506","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":10,"version":0,"name":"01508","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":11,"version":0,"name":"01512","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":12,"version":0,"name":"01514","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":13,"version":0,"name":"01516","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":14,"version":0,"name":"01517","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":15,"version":0,"name":"01518","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":16,"version":0,"name":"01524","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":17,"version":0,"name":"01529","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":18,"version":0,"name":"01532","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":19,"version":0,"name":"01538","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":20,"version":0,"name":"01540","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":21,"version":0,"name":"01546","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":22,"version":0,"name":"01550","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":23,"version":0,"name":"01551","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":24,"version":0,"name":"01556","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":25,"version":0,"name":"01560","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
{"resourceId":26,"version":0,"name":"01564","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true},
...
{"resourceId":3000,"version":0,"name":"01564","deleted":false,"defaultFlag":false,"cityId":1,"active":true}
```

## hazelcast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<!--
    The default Hazelcast configuration. This is used when:

    - no hazelcast.xml if present

-->
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.5.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="true">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <!--
            Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
            0 or * means use system provided port.
            -->
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="true">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="false">
                <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
                <member-list>
                    <member>127.0.0.1</member>
                </member-list>
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled="false">
                <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
                <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
                <!--optional, default is us-east-1 -->
                <region>us-west-1</region>
                <!--optional, default is ec2.amazonaws.com. If set, region shouldn't be set as it will override this property -->
                <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
                <!-- optional, only instances belonging to this group will be discovered, default will try all running instances -->
                <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
                <tag-key>type</tag-key>
                <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
            </aws>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="false">
            <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
        </interfaces>
        <ssl enabled="false"/>
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false"/>
        <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
            <!--
               encryption algorithm such as
               DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding,
               PBEWithMD5AndDES,
               AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding,
               Blowfish,
               DESede
            -->
            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
            <!-- salt value to use when generating the secret key -->
            <salt>thesalt</salt>
            <!-- pass phrase to use when generating the secret key -->
            <password>thepass</password>
            <!-- iteration count to use when generating the secret key -->
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>
    </network>
    <partition-group enabled="false"/>
    <executor-service name="default">
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
        <!--Queue capacity. 0 means Integer.MAX_VALUE.-->
        <queue-capacity>0</queue-capacity>
    </executor-service>
    <queue name="default">
        <!--
            Maximum size of the queue. When a JVM's local queue size reaches the maximum,
            all put/offer operations will get blocked until the queue size
            of the JVM goes down below the maximum.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
            Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-size>0</max-size>
        <!--
            Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
            then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
            fail-safety. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>

        <!--
            Number of async backups. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>

        <empty-queue-ttl>-1</empty-queue-ttl>
    </queue>
    <map name="default">
        <!--
           Data type that will be used for storing recordMap.
           Possible values:
           BINARY (default): keys and values will be stored as binary data
           OBJECT : values will be stored in their object forms
           NATIVE : values will be stored in non-heap region of JVM
        -->
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>

        <!--
            Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
            then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
            fail-safety. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <read-backup-data>false</read-backup-data>
        <!--
            Number of async backups. 0 means no backup.
        -->
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <!--
            Maximum number of seconds for each entry to stay in the map. Entries that are
            older than <time-to-live-seconds> and not updated for <time-to-live-seconds>
            will get automatically evicted from the map.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means infinite. Default is 0.
        -->
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <!--
            Maximum number of seconds for each entry to stay idle in the map. Entries that are
            idle(not touched) for more than <max-idle-seconds> will get
            automatically evicted from the map. Entry is touched if get, put or containsKey is called.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means infinite. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <!--
            Valid values are:
            NONE (no eviction),
            LRU (Least Recently Used),
            LFU (Least Frequently Used).
            NONE is the default.
        -->
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <!--
            Maximum size of the map. When max size is reached,
            map is evicted based on the policy defined.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
            Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
        <!--
            When max. size is reached, specified percentage of
            the map will be evicted. Any integer between 0 and 100.
            If 25 is set for example, 25% of the entries will
            get evicted.
        -->
        <eviction-percentage>100</eviction-percentage>
        <!--
            Minimum time in milliseconds which should pass before checking
            if a partition of this map is evictable or not.
            Default value is 100 millis.
        -->
        <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
        <!--
            While recovering from split-brain (network partitioning),
            map entries in the small cluster will merge into the bigger cluster
            based on the policy set here. When an entry merge into the
            cluster, there might an existing entry with the same key already.
            Values of these entries might be different for that same key.
            Which value should be set for the key? Conflict is resolved by
            the policy set here. Default policy is PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy

            There are built-in merge policies such as
            com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy; entry will be overwritten if merging entry exists for the key.
            com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy ; entry will be added if the merging entry doesn't exist in the cluster.
            com.hazelcast.map.merge.HigherHitsMapMergePolicy ; entry with the higher hits wins.
            com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy ; entry with the latest update wins.
        -->
        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>

    </map>

    <multimap name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <value-collection-type>SET</value-collection-type>
    </multimap>

    <list name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    </list>

    <set name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    </set>

    <jobtracker name="default">
        <max-thread-size>0</max-thread-size>
        <!-- Queue size 0 means number of partitions * 2 -->
        <queue-size>0</queue-size>
        <retry-count>0</retry-count>
        <chunk-size>1000</chunk-size>
        <communicate-stats>true</communicate-stats>
        <topology-changed-strategy>CANCEL_RUNNING_OPERATION</topology-changed-strategy>
    </jobtracker>

    <semaphore name="default">
        <initial-permits>0</initial-permits>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    </semaphore>

    <!--reliable-topic name="default">
        <read-batch-size>10</read-batch-size>
        <topic-overload-policy>BLOCK</topic-overload-policy>
        <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
    </reliable-topic>

    <ringbuffer name="default">
        <capacity>10000</capacity>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>30</time-to-live-seconds>
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    </ringbuffer-->

    <serialization>
        <portable-version>0</portable-version>
    </serialization>

    <services enable-defaults="true"/>

</hazelcast>
```

## hazelcast.config

```
JAVA_OPTS=" -server -Xms3000m -Xmx3000m -d64 -cp /opt/hazelcast/compile/hazelcast-3.5.5.jar:/opt/hazelcast/compile/hazelcast-client-3.5.5.jar:/opt/hazelcast/compile/hazelcast-hibernate4-3.5.5.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/annotations-1.3.2.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/cache-api-1.0.0.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/opt/hazelcast/provided/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar -Dhazelcast.config=/etc/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml -Dhazelcast.jmx=true"
```

## Hazel cast mancenter info

```
Number of Processors:   4
Start Time: Sat Oct 21 15:56:11 MYT 2017
Up Time:    0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 15 seconds
Maximum Memory: 2.81 GB
Total Memory:   2.81 GB
Free Memory:    2.45 GB
Used Heap Memory:   363.41 MB
Max Heap Memory:    2.81 GB
Used Non-Heap Memory:   24.47 MB
Max Non-Heap Memory:    214 MB
Total Loaded Classes:   4578
Current Loaded Classes: 4578
Total Unloaded Classes: 0
Total Thread Count: 40
Active Thread Count:    39
Peak Thread Count:  39
Daemon Thread Count:    5
OS: Free Physical Memory:   2.81 GB
OS: Committed Virtual Memory:   5.44 GB
OS: Total Physical Memory:  7.64 GB
OS: Free Swap Space:    16 GB
OS: Total Swap Space:   16 GB
OS: Maximum File Descriptor Count:  4096
OS: Open File Descriptor Count: 57
OS: Process CPU Time:   0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 7 seconds
OS: Process CPU Load:   4.0 %
OS: System Load Average:    25.0 %
OS: System CPU Load:    4.0 %
```

## Key and Data Structure

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

/**
 * <p>PostCode class.</p>
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "REF_POSTCODE",
       uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name", "city_id", "deleted_date" }) },
       indexes = { @Index(columnList = "city_id"),
                   @Index(columnList = "name")})
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE,
       region = "my.xxxxx.lookup.entity.PostCode")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString(callSuper = true)
public class PostCode extends AbstractEntity<Integer> {

    /** Constant <code>serialVersionUID=-8547924718051529341L</code> */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8547924718051529341L;

    @Id
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @TableGenerator(name = APP_SEQ_GENERATOR, table = APP_SEQ_TABLE, pkColumnName = SEQ_NAME_COL, pkColumnValue = "postCode.ID", valueColumnName = SEQ_VAL_COL, initialValue = INITIAL_VALUE, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = APP_SEQ_GENERATOR)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(length = 500)
    private String desp;

    @Column(name = "IS_DELETED")
    private boolean isDeleted = Boolean.FALSE;

    @Column(name = "DELETED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date deletedDate = EPOCH_DATE_TIME;

    @Column(name = "DEFAULT_FLAG")
    private boolean defaultFlag;

    @Column(name = "PREV_VERSION_ID")
    private Integer prevVersionId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE", nullable = false, columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE")
    private boolean isActive = Boolean.TRUE;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID", nullable = false)
    private City city;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if(null != this.id){
            return Objects.hash(this.id);
        }
        return Objects.hash(this.getName(), this.getDeletedDate());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj instanceof PostCode) {
            PostCode other = (PostCode) obj;
            return Objects.equals(this.hashCode(), other.hashCode());
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

## Persistence.properties

```
# Hibernate distributed secondary (L2) cache
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true
hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_native_client=true
hibernate.cache.hazelcast.native_client_address=10.1.2.1
```

## LOgfile

Hazelcast log file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByIpkcJW-nHLZjhyZEJ2a2RPSDQ

hazelcast Threaddump
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByIpkcJW-nHLMDdlQ0VWaU1taDA

tomcat Threaddump
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByIpkcJW-nHLZE5JamptdUNuZm8

## Version

JDK 1.8
Hazel cast 3.5

Comment: When you use two different Hazelcast instances, they use data back-up as default. It may be increasing the time spent for request if you are writing some data to Hazelcast. If data is removed and added to Hazelcast repeatedly, it can also cause this problem.

Additionally, [here][1] is how you can edit the back-up configuration: 


  [1]: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Map/Backing_Up_Maps.html

Comment: You can check the backups in the mancenter of Hazelcast if you are running less or equal to two instances.

Comment: hi @ahmetcetin , the performance is the same which is slow when no data being writen/removedso does back-up as default impacts the  time spent?

Answer (score 3):

I could not find any obvious configuration problem except you use very old version of Hazelcast. I suggest you update both Hazelcast and hazelcast-hibernate to the latest versions and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Few tips to improve performance here

1. Run min cluster of 3 nodes
2. Set read-from-backup to true if the data is mostly ready only
3. where possible enable near cache.
4. Tune hazelcast thread count and partition as per your hardware. (Details are in ref manual) http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#SystemProperties
5. Ensure clients are configured as smart clients

Answer (score 0):

We were observing significant performance issues when using Hazelcast 3.9. Upgrade to hazelcast version 3.11.4 showed significant improvement in the performance.